# Electric field and charge on an equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, equilibrium

ABC is a right equilateral triangle. An electric charge q is placed at A and an electric charge q' at B. The electric field at C is found to be parallel to the side AB, as shown by the arrow in the figure. Choose the appropriate formula from below which shows the relation between q and q' correctly.

[image]

The answer is given as j but I don't know why. I'm not even sure what they're asking to be honest.

Comment: Don't you mean a right-angle triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple concept involved here is that both the charges have their own fields if we check at point c the field due to q is in upward direction and that due to q' is inclined at an angle .since it is given that net field is horizontal I.e parallel to AB , it means net vertical field has to be 0 so equate the vertical fields due to the two charges

---

Note that one of the charges has to be negative( I assumed q' negative ) so that if field due to one is outwards then due to other must be inwards in order to cancel it . The only confusion here is equilateral right angled triangle . [image: ure added]

Answer (score 0):

the charge in B exerts a force in vertical and horizontal direction proportional to q/CB^2 the force in A excerpts force only vertical. The force and therefore E should  be horizontal, so the vertical forces have to cancel. Now you should be able to calculate,